# C / Como fazer o cálculo de média nesse programa?

Tags: c

Olá, esse programa pede um número de pessoas, depois armazena informações na struct. Minha duvida é: Como fazer para o programa calcular a média das alturas?   Cálculo está comentando

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    typedef struct {
  int cpf;
  int idade;
  float altura;

          } Pessoa;

        Pessoa *vpn;

int i, cont, n;
float media;

printf(" Insira numero de pessoas: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

vpn = (Pessoa *)malloc(n*sizeof(Pessoa));
if (vpn==NULL) return ;
//================================================
for (i=0;i<n;i++){

      printf(" Insida o CPF: " );
      scanf("%d", &(vpn[i].cpf) );

      printf(" Insida a idade: " );
      scanf("%d", &(vpn[i].idade) );

      printf(" Insida a altura: " );
      scanf("%f", &(vpn[i].altura));
      printf(" ======================\n");
    }

     media = (vpn[i].altura) / n;  //COMO SERIA ESSE CALCULO DE MÉDIA?
                                   // a média das alturas contidas em vpn altura

     printf("MEDIA: %f.\n",media); //imprima na tela a média das alturas contidas em vnp.

     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: A média é a soma pela quantidade, então crie uma variável que receberá a soma de todas as alturas e divida-a por n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `struct` tem de ser definida fora do `main` caso pretenda usar para outras funções.

```
 typedef struct {
  int n;
  int cpf;
  int idade;
  float altura; } Pessoa;
int main(){
 ...
}
```

- **Dentro da main**- Apenas pode ser acessada dentro da `main`
- **Fora da main** - Pode ser acessada fora da `main`

---

*Média = Somatório das alturas / numero total de pessoas*

```
int soma=0;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
     soma += vpn[i].altura;

media=(float)soma/n;
```

Muito importante esse cast `(float)`, como `soma` e `vpn.altura` são 2 **inteiros** o resultado vinha em inteiro, ou seja, usamos esse cast para a media vir em `float` como queremos.

[Type Casting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm)

- Média sem cast: 5/3 = 2 <- **Int**
- Média com cast: 5/3 = 2.5 <- **Float**

Comment: Fiz assim e deu certo também ! Tudo Certo!!!    
float soma=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
         soma += vpn[i].altura;

    media=soma/n;

          printf("MEDIA: %.2f\n",media);

Comment: Sim, o problema é dividir um `int` por outro `int`, como declarou `float soma` não ha esse problema já